# Set Ceph endpoint to DNS doesn't work in Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata, ceph

I'm trying to enabling big data environment which contains Hadoop (2.7), Spark(2.3) and Ceph(luminous). 
Before changing `fs.s3a.endpoint` to Domain Name, everything worked fine just as expected.

The key part of `core-site.xml` is like below:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>s3a://tpcds</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>http://10.1.2.213:8080</value>
</property>
```

However, when I changed the `fs.s3a.endpoint` to Domain Name like below:

```
<property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>http://gw.gearon.com:8080</value>
</property>
```

And I tried to launch SparkSQL on the Hadoop Yarn, the error like below throws:

```
AmazonHttpClient:448 - Unable to execute HTTP request: tpcds.gw.gearon.com: Name or service not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: tpcds.gw.gearon.com: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
```

The `gw.gearon.com` is forwarded to `10.1.2.213` for sure. After googling, I realized one more attribute should be set.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.path.style.access</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Enable S3 path style access ie disabling the default virtual hosting behaviour.
    Useful for S3A-compliant storage providers as it removes the need to set up DNS for virtual hosting.
  </description>
</property>
```

After setting `fs.s3a.path.style.access` to `true`, the error disappears when launching Hadoop Map-Reduce. However, for `Spark-SQL` on Hadoop Yarn, the error still exists. I thought maybe Spark overrides Hadoop's settings, so I also append `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access   true` to `spark-defaults.xml`, it still doesn't work.

So here come to the question: 
 The `endpoint` I set is `http://gw.gearon.com:8080`, why the error showed me `tpcds.gw.gearon.com` is unknown? The `tpcds` is my Ceph bucket name I set it as my `fs.defaultFS`, it looks fine in `core-site.xml`. How can I solve the issue?

Any comment is welcomed and thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "amazon naming methods", as described [here](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/https-ization-ceph-object-storage-public-endpoint) and [here](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/install/install-ceph-gateway/#add-wildcard-to-dns).

That is, point a wildcard dns CNAME to the name of the gateway(s):

```
*.gw.gearon.com CNAME 10.1.2.213
```

Also be sure to properly setup that name into the gateways (documentation [here](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/emperor/radosgw/config/#enabling-subdomain-s3-calls)):

```
rgw dns name = clover.voxelgroup.net
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two comments here: 1. The *.gw.gearon.com CNAME 10.1.2.213 should be *.gw.gearon.com IN CNAME 10.1.2.213, right? 2, The {hostname} in my case should be gw.gearon.com, right? Namely `rgw dns name = gw.gearon.com`?

Comment: 1. Correct if you're using bind, that is not my case for example. 2 Correct, if you look at the error you've posted: `Unable to execute HTTP request: tpcds.gw.gearon.com` the key to find the problem is that SparkSQL is using this naming method to call ceph: `bucket.gateway.domain.com` which is supposed to be the standard one.